# Why does my background image get bigger according to screen resolution?

Tags: css

On 320×480 on mobile, my background image, and the word it contains, fits perfectly to the screen. As soon as I look at it on a mobile with 320×568, the images gets slightly bigger and the end of the word gets chopped off the screen. Any size above 320×480 on mobile, the image is slightly too big.

I used this css to change the button layout, and it worked, except that the background image still gets slightly bigger above 320×480.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.btn { 
display: inline-block; 
height: 40px; 
font-size: 12px; 
width: 145px; 
min-width: 80px; 
padding: 0;margin-top: 180px; text-align: center; content: 
center; line-height: 38px;
```

It's just the background image on the front page which I'm concerned about.

I tried:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { body
{background-image: contain;


}} 

@media (max-width: 768px) {img {max-width: 100%; 
height: auto;}}
```

Didn't work.

Tried:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { body
{background-size: contain;
}} 

@media (max-width: 768px) {img {background-size: 
contain;}}
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: What is `background-image: contain` ? You can use `background-size:contain` for this.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work

Comment: ok. you can add your all code.

Comment: Can you try with `img{ object-fit: contain}`

Comment: What do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: With a media query?

Comment: `@media (max-width: 768px) {img {object-fit: contain;}} `

Comment: Nope. Nothing..